# Step-up transformers with varying voltage outputs in parallel on single line?

Tags: transformer, step-up

Just curious if this is possible.  I also know this is very simplistic.

Say I have an AC generator that outputs 24V.  I have three separate devices that each require a different, increased voltage to operate.  Can I put three separate step-up transformers in parallel, each stepping up different voltages?

I drew this diagram to help explain what I mean.  The "G" is the generator, "T" is the transformer, and "D" is the device.

[image: (]

Comment: @DontPanic, see the revision history. Hit the "edited *x time* ago" link.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can be done, however it may be more economic to use a single autotransformer with multiple taps.

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine -- this is basically the way all systems in your house are connected -- the primaries of the individual transformers are in parallel (i.e. plugged into the mains), and the secondaries are all separate.